# Why Gauss's law for gravity can be applied to this problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, symmetry, gauss-law

> Consider a spherical and homogeneous celestial body with mass $ M $ and radius $ R $ crossed from pole to pole by a straight cylindrical tunnel of negligible diameter. At one of these poles a point object is released from rest at $t = 0$. Since $G$ is the universal gravitation constant, this object will reach the other pole after the time interval given by:

Answer: $\pi \left(\frac{R^3}{GM}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

One of the most viable ways to solve this problem is using [Gauss's law for gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_gravity). But why? Could someone give me some explanation of why Gauss's law for gravity can be applied to this problem? Why is it often used instead of Newton's law?

Comment: I don't know I never used this technique to solve this instead the solution is simple The particle will undergo SHM and the value for the time interval will be T/2. Where T is the time period which can be easily calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In suitable units the field equation that you have to solve is
\begin{equation} 
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{G} = \rho 
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{G}$ is the gravitational field and $\rho$ is the density of the earth. Now integrate this up to some radius $R < R_\text{earth}$,
\begin{equation} 
\int_{S_2(R)} d^3x \; \nabla \cdot \mathbf{G} = \int_{S_2(R)} d^3x \; \rho 
\end{equation}
here is where we can make use of Gauss' law to write
\begin{equation} 
\int d \mathbf{S} \cdot \mathbf{G} = \frac{4}{3} \pi R^3 \rho 
\end{equation}
The symmetry of the problem suggests that $\mathbf{G}$ must always point in a radial direction. This is important. For general problems, this method does not work and you have to go back to a Green's function approach. But here things are easier and we can solve the integral directly,
\begin{equation} 
4\pi R^2 |\mathbf{G}| = \frac{4}{3}\pi R^3 \rho.
\end{equation}
The equation of motion of your falling body is now
\begin{equation} 
m \ddot{R} + m \frac{R \rho}{3} = 0,
\end{equation}
which we recognize as an harmonic oscillator with $\omega^2 = \frac{ \rho}{3}$. Upon replacing $\rho = 3M/4\pi R^3$ and switching to SI-units, you obtain from this the correct period time.